# Es más eficiente cargar recursos al empezar el juego, o sobre la marcha según se vayan necesitando?

Tags: c++, game

Me encuentro actualmente haciendo un juego sencillo en C++ y SDL2 por diversión.
Tengo una clase 'Actor' que tiene un número fijo de estados posibles (parado, andando, corriendo...) cada uno con su 'sprite' propio, y a la hora de escribir el constructor me ha surgido una duda: ya que es muy probable que ese 'Actor' use todos sus estados en algún momento (puede que algún virtuoso se pueda pasar el juego sin disparar o correr pero no creo ;)), sería mejor esto :

```
#include"Entity.h"
#include"ActorStateMachine.h"
#include"ActorStateMoving.h"

class Actor : public Entity
{
    std::unique_ptr<ActorStateMachine>m_pASM;
public:
    Actor():Entity() 
    {
        m_pASM = std::make_unique<ActorStateMachine>();
        m_pASM->pushState(std::make_unique<ActorStateMoving>());
    }
   ~ActorSnake() {}

}
```

O sea incluir un vector de estados como miembro de la clase, añadir un primer estado en el constructor, e ir incluyendo y eliminando de él los estados según transcurra el juego.

O esto otro :

```
#include"Entity.h"
#include"ActorStateMoving.h"
#include"ActorStateJumping.h"
#include"ActorStateFiring.h"

class Actor : public Entity
{
    ActorStateMoving m_moving;
    ActorStateJumping m_jumping;
    ActorStateFiring m_firing;
    etc....

public:
    Actor():Entity() {}
   ~Actor() {}

}
```

O sea incluir los estados directamente como miembros de la clase ya que van a ser usados seguro y así evitar tener que 'crearlos' en tiempo de ejecución gastando ciclos de CPU.

Al ser un juego sencillo y con 'sprites' livianos igual da lo mismo pero me gustaría saber cual es la mejor y más eficiente manera por si en el futuro meto 'sprites' más elaborados.

Muchas gracias por vuestro tiempo.

Comment: No se si acabo de entender tu duda. La práctica habitual es cargar los recursos necesarios antes del estado inicial del juego para posteriormente usarlos. El Actor no tiene responsabilidad de carga/descarga de recursos si no de uso. Deberías redactar un gestor de recursos y el Actor debería solicitar sus recursos a dicho gestor.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster si, no me he expresado con demasiada claridad. Los estados del 'Actor' cambian en base a los eventos del juego (que reciba un disparo por ejemplo) o la entrada del usuario (que pulse 'fuego') y es una máquina de estados finitos la que lo cambia (actualiza). Hasta aquí todo normal, lo que me intriga es si es mejor, más eficiente de cara al rendimiento y fluidez del juego, el crear y eliminar en tiempo 'real' estados de un vector de los mismos que posea la clase 'Actor' o incluir dichos estados desde el principio como miembros de la clase.

Comment: Creo que sigo sin entender tu pregunta. ¿Qué te supone un problema? ¿La creación de estados sobre la marcha o el hecho de que estos estados carguen/descarguen recursos (*sprites*)?. Si la duda es lo primero: no te preocupes, crea/destruye estados sobre la marcha. Si la duda es lo segundo: preocúpate, los recursos deben cargarse/descargarse una vez no sobre la marcha.

Comment: Respecto a la eficiencia (que está mencionada en el título de la pregunta) los recursos (*sprites*) por pequeños que sean, siempre será más eficiente cargarlos una sola vez que una vez por estado. Piensa que un *sprite* de 10×10 a 32bpp son 32×10×10 bytes (algo más de 3k de memoria) y crece cuadráticamente según el tamaño del *sprite*.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster muchas gracias por los comentarios. He editado la pregunta incluyendo una pequeña muestra de código para ver si queda más clara.

Comment: Toda operación tiene coste. Hacer una operación varias veces tiene un coste lineal creciente en el número de veces que haces la operación ([O(n)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cota_superior_asintótica#Órdenes_usuales_para_funciones)). Por lo tanto: a la pregunta de ¿Qué es más eficiente? la respuesta, si medimos el tiempo de proceso, será siempre: hacer las cosas una sola vez.